# Cannot load materials to Android application

Tags: android, import, runtime

I am trying to make application using this script in Unity(It loads Obj. model files in Runtime) :

```
    /* OBJ file tags */
    private const string O  = "o";
    private const string G  = "g";
    private const string V  = "v";
    private const string VT = "vt";
    private const string VN = "vn";
    private const string F  = "f";
    private const string MTL = "mtllib";
    private const string UML = "usemtl";

    /* MTL file tags */
    private const string NML = "newmtl";
    private const string NS = "Ns"; // Shininess
    private const string KA = "Ka"; // Ambient component (not supported)
    private const string KD = "Kd"; // Diffuse component
    private const string KE = "Ke"; // Emissive / Self Illum component
    private const string KS = "Ks"; // Specular component
    private const string D = "d";   // Transparency (not supported)
    private const string TR = "Tr"; // Same as 'd'
    private const string ILLUM = "illum"; // Illumination model. 1 - diffuse, 2 - specular
    private const string MAP_KA = "map_Ka"; // Ambient texture //Not Implemented 
    private const string MAP_KD = "map_Kd"; // Diffuse texture 
    private const string MAP_KS = "map_Ks"; // Specular texture 
    private const string MAP_KE = "map_Ke"; // Self-Illumination or Emmisive texture
    private const string MAP_D = "map_d"; // Alpha texture or -
    private const string MAP_TR = "map_tr"; //  Alpha texture 
    private const string MAP_BUMP = "map_bump"; // Bump texture (Reflection, Refraction,Displacement textures are not supported currently)

    private string basepath;
    private string mtllib;

    private GeometryBuffer buffer;
    private Texture2D[] TMPTextures;

    ///Initialiser
    void Start() {
        buffer = new GeometryBuffer ();
        if (objPath!="") {
            if (!objPath.Contains("http://")) {
                basepath=Path.GetDirectoryName(objPath);
                objPath="file://"+objPath;
                basepath="file://"+basepath+Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
            } else {
                basepath = (objPath.IndexOf("/") == -1) ? "" : objPath.Substring(0, objPath.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            }
            StartCoroutine (Load (objPath));
        }
    }

    ///Main Loop
    public IEnumerator Load(string path) {
        WWW loader = new WWW(path);
        yield return loader;
        if (loader.error != null) {
            Debug.Log("File Not Found");   //!!!!!
        } else {
            SetGeometryData(loader.text);
        }

        if (buffer.Check(true,false)) { //buffer.Trace(AutoResolveVLimit)
            if(hasMaterials) {
                loader = new WWW(ResolvePath(mtllib,basepath));
                yield return loader;
                if (loader.error != null) {
                    Debug.Log("failed to resolve material library path"+basepath+mtllib);  //!!!!!
                    string[] emats=buffer.ReturnMaterialNames(); 
                    materialData = new List<MaterialData>();
                    MaterialData nmd = new MaterialData();
                    foreach(string mname in emats) {
                        nmd = new MaterialData();
                        nmd.name = mname;
                        nmd.ShaderName="Diffuse";
                        nmd.diffuse = new Color(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
                        materialData.Add(nmd);
                    }
                } else {
                    SetMaterialData(loader.text);                       
                    TMPTextures=new Texture2D[TextureList.Count];
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int>txt in TextureList) {
                        string imgext=Path.GetExtension(txt.Key);
                        if (imgext==".jpg"||imgext==".jpeg"||imgext==".png") {
                            WWW texloader = new WWW(ResolvePath(txt.Key,basepath));
                            yield return texloader;
                            if (texloader.error != null) {                                                                                  
                                Debug.Log("failed to resolve texture path"+basepath+txt.Key);
                            } else {
                                TMPTextures[txt.Value]=texloader.texture;           
                            }
                        } else {
                            Debug.Log(txt.Key+": image not correct file type please use jpeg or png");  //!!!!
                        }
                    }
                    SolveMaterials();
                }   
            } 
            CheckScale();
            Build();
        } else {
            Debug.Log("Too many poly's");
        }
        Destroy (this);
    }
    //Set ScaleOffset data for object or master group
    private void pushscaleoffset(scaleoffset so,Vector3 v) {
        if (!so.initval) {
            so.minvxpos=v.x;
            so.maxvxpos=v.x;
            so.minvypos=v.y;
            so.maxvypos=v.y;
            so.minvzpos=v.z;
            so.maxvzpos=v.z;
            so.initval=true;
        } else {
            so.minvxpos=v.x<so.minvxpos?v.x:so.minvxpos;
            so.maxvxpos=v.x>so.maxvxpos?v.x:so.maxvxpos;
            so.minvypos=v.y<so.minvypos?v.y:so.minvypos;
            so.maxvypos=v.y>so.maxvypos?v.y:so.maxvypos;
            so.minvzpos=v.z<so.minvzpos?v.z:so.minvzpos;
            so.maxvzpos=v.z>so.maxvzpos?v.z:so.maxvzpos;
        }
    }
    ///Geometry
    private void SetGeometryData(string data) {
        data = data.Replace("\r\n","\n");
        string[] lines = data.Split("\n".ToCharArray()); 
        Vector3 v;
        mainso = new scaleoffset();
        for(int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++) {
            string l = lines[i];
            l=Regex.Replace(l,@"# object","o");//tomekkie ALTERATION
            if(l.IndexOf("#") != -1) l = l.Substring(0, l.IndexOf("#"));
            l=Regex.Replace(l,@"\s+"," ");
            l=l.Trim();
            string[] p = l.Split(" ".ToCharArray());  
            switch(p[0]) {
                case O:
                    if (!EnforceSingleObj) {
                        if (currentso!=null) {
                            currentso.vlast=vcount;
                            objso.Add(currentso);
                        }
                        buffer.PushObject(p[1].Trim());
                        currentso = new scaleoffset();
                        currentso.vfirst=vcount;
                        currentso.name=p[1].Trim();
                    }
                    break;
                case G:
                    buffer.PushGroup(p[1].Trim());
                    break;
                case V:     
                    if (p.Length>=3) {
                        v=new Vector3(cf(p[1]),cf(p[2]),0-cf(p[3]));
                        buffer.PushVertex(v);    //Any 0- Flipping should match normals
                        vcount++;
                        pushscaleoffset(mainso,v);
                        if (currentso!=null) {
                            pushscaleoffset(currentso,v);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case VT:
                    if (p.Length>=2) {
                        buffer.PushUV(new Vector2( cf(p[1]), cf(p[2]) ));
                    }
                    break;
                case VN:
                    if (p.Length>=3) {
                        buffer.PushNormal(new Vector3(cf(p[1]),cf(p[2]),0-cf(p[3]))); //Any 0- Flipping should match vertex
                    }
                    break;
                case F:
                    if (p.Length>=4) { 
                        if (p.Length<=5) {//is triangle or quad
                            string[] c;
                            for (int j=0;j<p.Length-3;j++) {    //get all possible triangles from line
                                FaceIndices fi = new FaceIndices(); //1 vert
                                    c=p[1].Trim().Split("/".ToCharArray());
                                    if (c.Length > 0 && c[0] != string.Empty) {fi.vi = ci(c[0])-1;}
                                    if (c.Length > 1 && c[1] != string.Empty) {fi.vu = ci(c[1])-1;}
                                    if (c.Length > 2 && c[2] != string.Empty) {fi.vn = ci(c[2])-1;}
                                buffer.PushFace(fi);
                                for (int k=0;k<2;k++) { //2nd and 3rd vert
                                    fi = new FaceIndices(); 
                                        int no=3-k+j; //        To invert faces replace with : int no=2+k+j;
                                        c=p[no].Trim().Split("/".ToCharArray());
                                        if (c.Length > 0 && c[0] != string.Empty) {fi.vi = ci(c[0])-1;}
                                        if (c.Length > 1 && c[1] != string.Empty) {fi.vu = ci(c[1])-1;}
                                        if (c.Length > 2 && c[2] != string.Empty) {fi.vn = ci(c[2])-1;}
                                    buffer.PushFace(fi);
                                }
                            }
                        } else { //is poly try triangulate, see TriPoly script
                            TriPoly triangulation;
                            triangulation = new TriPoly();
                            Vector3[] pointlist=new Vector3[p.Length-1];
                            //Vector3[] normallist=new Vector3[p.Length-1];
                            string[] c;
                            for (int j=1;j<p.Length;j++) { //go through each faceindex in poly list and pull relevant vertice from geometrybuffer add to vector[]
                                c=p[j].Trim().Split("/".ToCharArray());
                                if (c.Length > 0 && c[0] != string.Empty) {pointlist[j-1] = buffer.vertices[ci(c[0])-1];}
                                //if (c.Length > 2 && c[2] != string.Empty) {normallist[j-1] = buffer.normals[ci(c[2])-1];}
                            }
                            int[] indices;
                            //if (normallist!=null) {
                            //  indices=triangulation.Patch(pointlist, normallist);
                            //} else {
                                indices=triangulation.Patch(pointlist); //, normallist
                            //}
                            if (indices.Length>2) {
                                for (int j=0;j<indices.Length;++j) { //may need to reverse this?
                                    FaceIndices fi = new FaceIndices(); 
                                        c=p[indices[j]+1].Trim().Split("/".ToCharArray());
                                        if (c.Length > 0 && c[0] != string.Empty) {fi.vi = ci(c[0])-1;}
                                        if (c.Length > 1 && c[1] != string.Empty) {fi.vu = ci(c[1])-1;}
                                        if (c.Length > 2 && c[2] != string.Empty) {fi.vn = ci(c[2])-1;}
                                    buffer.PushFace(fi);
                                }
                            } 
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case MTL:
                    mtllib = p[1].Trim();
                    break;
                case UML:
                    buffer.PushMaterialGroup(p[1].Trim()); //hello
                    break;
            }
        }
        if (currentso!=null) {
            currentso.vlast=vcount;
            objso.Add(currentso);
        }
    }

    private void CalculateScaleOffset(scaleoffset so,bool above){
        so.MasterOffsetx=0.0f-((so.maxvxpos/2.0f)+(so.minvxpos/2.0f));
        so.MasterOffsety=0.0f-((so.maxvypos/2.0f)+(so.minvypos/2.0f));
        so.MasterOffsetz=0.0f-((so.maxvzpos/2.0f)+(so.minvzpos/2.0f));
        if (above) { //UPrestingonzero
            so.MainOffset=new Vector3(so.MasterOffsetx,so.MasterOffsety+((so.maxvypos-so.minvypos)/2.0f),so.MasterOffsetz);
        } else { //UpCentred
            so.MainOffset=new Vector3(so.MasterOffsetx,so.MasterOffsety,so.MasterOffsetz);
        }
        so.minvpos=so.minvypos<so.minvxpos?so.minvypos:so.minvxpos;
        so.minvpos=so.minvzpos<so.minvpos?so.minvzpos:so.minvpos;
        so.maxvpos=so.maxvypos>so.maxvxpos?so.maxvypos:so.maxvxpos;
        so.maxvpos=so.maxvzpos>so.maxvpos?so.maxvzpos:so.maxvpos;
        float ep=0.0F;
        ep=(0-so.minvpos)>so.maxvpos?(0-so.minvpos):so.maxvpos;
        if (ep!=0.0f) {
            if (ep>objmaxsize) so.MasterScale=objmaxsize/ep;
            if (ep<objminsize) so.MasterScale=objminsize/ep;
        } else {
            so.MasterScale=1.0f;
        }
    }

    private void CheckScale() {
        CalculateScaleOffset(mainso,true);
        if (!EnforceSingleObj && objso.Count>1) {
            treatasoneobject=false;
            foreach(scaleoffset so in objso) {
                CalculateScaleOffset(so,false);
                for(int i=so.vfirst;i<so.vlast;i++) {
                    buffer.vertices[i]=(buffer.vertices[i]+so.MainOffset)*mainso.MasterScale;
                }
            }
        } else {
            treatasoneobject=true;
            for(int i=0;i<buffer.vertices.Count;i++) {
                buffer.vertices[i]=(buffer.vertices[i]+mainso.MainOffset)*mainso.MasterScale;
            }
        }
    }

    private float cf(string v) {
            return Convert.ToSingle(v.Trim(), new CultureInfo("en-US"));
    }

    private int ci(string v) {
            return Convert.ToInt32(v.Trim(), new CultureInfo("en-US"));
    }

    ///Materials
    private Color gc(string[] p) {
        return new Color( cf(p[1]), cf(p[2]), cf(p[3]) );
    }

    private bool hasMaterials {
        get {
            return mtllib != null;
        }
    }

    Dictionary<string, int> TextureList = new Dictionary<string, int>();  
    private List<MaterialData> materialData;
    private class MaterialData {
        public string name;
        public Color ambient;
        public Color diffuse;
        public Color specular;
        public Color emmisive;
        public bool emmision=false;
        public float shininess;
        public float alpha=1.0f;
        public int illumType;
        public string ambientTexPath;
        public string diffuseTexPath;
        public string emmisiveTexPath;
        public string specularTexPath;
        public string alphaTexPath;
        public string bumpTexPath;
        public Texture2D DiffTexture; 
        public Texture2D BumpTexture;
        public Texture2D EmmisiveTexture;
        public string ShaderName;
    }

    private void SetMaterialData(string data) {
        data = data.Replace("\r\n","\n");
        string[] lines = data.Split("\n".ToCharArray());        
        materialData = new List<MaterialData>();
        MaterialData current = new MaterialData();
        int texturecount=0;     
        for(int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++) {
            string l = lines[i];            
            if(l.IndexOf("#") != -1) l = l.Substring(0, l.IndexOf("#"));
            l=Regex.Replace(l,@"\s+"," ");
            l=l.Trim();         
            string[] p = l.Split(" ".ToCharArray());
            switch(p[0]) {
                case NML:
                    current = new MaterialData();
                    current.name = p[1].Trim();
                    materialData.Add(current);
                    break;
                case KA:
                    current.ambient = gc(p);
                    break;
                case KD:
                    current.diffuse = gc(p);
                    break;
                case KS:
                    current.specular = gc(p);
                    break;
                case KE:
                    current.emmisive = gc(p);
                    if (current.emmisive.grayscale>0.0f) {
                        current.emmision=true;
                    }
                    break;
                case NS:
                    current.shininess = cf(p[1]) / 1000;
                    break;
                case D:
                    current.alpha = 1.0f-cf(p[1]);
                    break;
                case TR:
                    current.alpha = 1.0f-cf(p[1]);
                    break;
                case MAP_KA: //ambiant - not currently utilised
                    current.ambientTexPath = p[p.Length-1].Trim();
                    if (!TextureList.ContainsKey(p[p.Length-1].Trim())) { 
                        TextureList.Add(p[p.Length-1].Trim(), texturecount);
                        texturecount++;
                    }
                    break;
                case MAP_KD:  //diffuse
                    current.diffuseTexPath = p[p.Length-1].Trim();
                    if (!TextureList.ContainsKey(p[p.Length-1].Trim())) { 
                        TextureList.Add(p[p.Length-1].Trim(), texturecount);
                        texturecount++;
                    }
                    break;
                case MAP_KE: //emmisive
                    current.emmisiveTexPath = p[p.Length-1].Trim();
                    if (!TextureList.ContainsKey(p[p.Length-1].Trim())) { 
                        TextureList.Add(p[p.Length-1].Trim(), texturecount);
                        texturecount++;
                    }
                    break;
                case MAP_KS: //specular
                    current.specularTexPath = p[p.Length-1].Trim();
                    if (!TextureList.ContainsKey(p[p.Length-1].Trim())) { 
                        TextureList.Add(p[p.Length-1].Trim(), texturecount);
                        texturecount++;
                    }
                    break;
                case MAP_D: //alpha 
                    current.alphaTexPath = p[p.Length-1].Trim();
                    if (!TextureList.ContainsKey(p[p.Length-1].Trim())) { 
                        TextureList.Add(p[p.Length-1].Trim(), texturecount);
                        texturecount++;
                    }
                    break;
                case MAP_TR: //alpha
                    current.alphaTexPath = p[p.Length-1].Trim();
                    if (!TextureList.ContainsKey(p[p.Length-1].Trim())) { 
                        TextureList.Add(p[p.Length-1].Trim(), texturecount);
                        texturecount++;
                    }
                    break;
                case MAP_BUMP: //bump
                    current.bumpTexPath = p[p.Length-1].Trim();
                    if (!TextureList.ContainsKey(p[p.Length-1].Trim())) { 
                        TextureList.Add(p[p.Length-1].Trim(), texturecount);
                        texturecount++;
                    }
                    break;
                case ILLUM:
                    current.illumType = ci(p[1]);
                    break;
            }
        }   
    }


    private void SolveMaterials() {
        Color[] src;
        Color[] dest;
        Color[] tmp;
        foreach(MaterialData m in materialData) { 
            Texture2D AlphaChannel=new Texture2D(2,2);
            //Match with Shader
            bool alph=false;
            bool emistxt=false;
            m.ShaderName="";
            if (m.alpha==1.0&&m.alphaTexPath==null) {
                if (m.emmision||m.emmisiveTexPath!=null) {
                    m.ShaderName+="Self-Illumin/";
                    if (m.emmisiveTexPath!=null) {
                        if (TextureList.ContainsKey(m.emmisiveTexPath)) {
                            AlphaChannel=TMPTextures[TextureList[m.emmisiveTexPath]];
                            emistxt=true;
                            alph=true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (m.alpha==1.0) {
                    m.ShaderName+="Transparent/Cutout/";
                    if (m.alphaTexPath!=null) {
                        if (TextureList.ContainsKey(m.alphaTexPath)) {
                            AlphaChannel=TMPTextures[TextureList[m.alphaTexPath]];
                            alph=true;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    m.ShaderName+="Transparent/";
                    if (m.alphaTexPath!=null) {
                        if (TextureList.ContainsKey(m.alphaTexPath)) {
                            AlphaChannel=TMPTextures[TextureList[m.alphaTexPath]];
                            alph=true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (m.bumpTexPath!=null) {
                if (TextureList.ContainsKey(m.bumpTexPath)){
                    m.ShaderName+="Bumped ";
                    m.BumpTexture=TMPTextures[TextureList[m.bumpTexPath]];
                }
            }
            if(m.shininess>0.01||m.specularTexPath!=null) {
                m.ShaderName+="Specular";
                if (m.specularTexPath!=null) {
                    if (!alph&&TextureList.ContainsKey(m.specularTexPath)) {
                        AlphaChannel=TMPTextures[TextureList[m.specularTexPath]];
                        alph=true;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                m.ShaderName+="Diffuse";
            }
            if (m.diffuseTexPath!=null) {
                if (TextureList.ContainsKey(m.diffuseTexPath)) {            
                    m.DiffTexture=TMPTextures[TextureList[m.diffuseTexPath]];
                }
            }

            // Process Required Textures
            Texture2D Temp;
            if (alph) { 
                if (m.DiffTexture!=null) {
                    AlphaChannel=ScaleTexture(AlphaChannel,m.DiffTexture.width,m.DiffTexture.height);
                    Temp=new Texture2D(m.DiffTexture.width,m.DiffTexture.height,TextureFormat.ARGB32,false);
                } else {
                    m.DiffTexture=new Texture2D(AlphaChannel.width,AlphaChannel.height,TextureFormat.ARGB32,false);
                    Temp=new Texture2D(AlphaChannel.width,AlphaChannel.height,TextureFormat.ARGB32,false);
                }
                src=AlphaChannel.GetPixels(0);
                dest=m.DiffTexture.GetPixels(0);
                tmp=Temp.GetPixels(0);
                int px=0;
                if (!emistxt) {
                    if (AlphaChannel.format==TextureFormat.ARGB32) {
                        if (m.diffuseTexPath==null) {
                            for(px=0; px<tmp.Length; px++) {
                                tmp[px] = new Color(0.5F,0.5F,0.5F,src[px].a);
                            }
                        } else {
                            for(px=0; px<tmp.Length;px++) {
                                tmp[px] = new Color(dest[px].r,dest[px].g,dest[px].b,src[px].a);
                            }                       
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (m.diffuseTexPath==null) {
                            for(px=0; px<tmp.Length;px++) {
                                tmp[px] = new Color(0.5F,0.5F,0.5F,src[px].grayscale);
                            }
                        } else {
                            for(px=0; px<tmp.Length;px++) {
                                tmp[px] = new Color(dest[px].r,dest[px].g,dest[px].b,src[px].grayscale);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Temp.SetPixels(tmp,0);
                    m.DiffTexture=Temp;
                    m.DiffTexture.SetPixels(m.DiffTexture.GetPixels()); 
                    m.DiffTexture.Apply(true);
                    m.DiffTexture.Compress(true);
                } else {
                    if (AlphaChannel.format==TextureFormat.ARGB32) {
                        for(px=0; px<tmp.Length; px++) {tmp[px] = new Color(1.0F,1.0F,1.0F,src[px].a);}
                    } else {
                        for(px=0; px<tmp.Length; px++) {tmp[px] = new Color(1.0F,1.0F,1.0F,src[px].grayscale);}
                    }
                    Temp.SetPixels(tmp,0);
                    m.EmmisiveTexture=Temp;
                    m.EmmisiveTexture.SetPixels(m.EmmisiveTexture.GetPixels());
                    m.EmmisiveTexture.Apply(true);
                    m.EmmisiveTexture.Compress(true);
                }
            } else {
                if (m.DiffTexture!=null) { 
                    Temp=new Texture2D(m.DiffTexture.width,m.DiffTexture.height,TextureFormat.ARGB32,false);
                    tmp=m.DiffTexture.GetPixels(0);
                    Temp.SetPixels(tmp,0);
                    m.DiffTexture=Temp;
                    m.DiffTexture.SetPixels(m.DiffTexture.GetPixels());
                    m.DiffTexture.Apply(true);
                    m.DiffTexture.Compress(true);
                }
            }
            if (m.BumpTexture!=null) {          
                m.BumpTexture=NormalMap(m.BumpTexture,BumpStrength);
                m.BumpTexture.filterMode=FilterMode.Trilinear;
                m.BumpTexture.Compress(true);
            }
        }
    }


    private Material GetMaterial(MaterialData md) {
        Material m;     
        m=new Material(Shader.Find(md.ShaderName));
        m.SetColor("_Color", md.diffuse);
        if (md.ShaderName.Contains("Self-Illumin")) {
            if(md.EmmisiveTexture!=null) m.SetTexture("_Illum",md.EmmisiveTexture);
            if (md.emmision) {
                m.SetColor("_Color", md.emmisive);
            }
        }
        if (md.ShaderName.Contains("Transparent")) {
            m.SetColor("_Color", new Color(md.diffuse.r,md.diffuse.g,md.diffuse.b,md.alpha));
        }
        if (md.ShaderName.Contains("Cutout")) {
            m.SetFloat("_Cutoff",0.5F);
        }
        if (md.ShaderName.Contains("Specular")) {
            m.SetColor("_SpecColor", md.specular);
            m.SetFloat("_Shininess", md.shininess);
        }
        if(md.DiffTexture!=null) m.SetTexture("_MainTex",md.DiffTexture);
        if(md.BumpTexture!=null) m.SetTexture("_BumpMap",md.BumpTexture);
        return m;
    }

    ///Assemble
    private void Build() {
        Dictionary<string, Material> materials = new Dictionary<string, Material>();
        if(hasMaterials) {
            Material m =  new Material(Shader.Find("Diffuse"));
            m.SetColor("_Color", new Color(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f)); 
            materials.Add("_spc_default", m); 
            foreach(MaterialData md in materialData) {
                if (!materials.ContainsKey(md.name)) {
                    materials.Add(md.name, GetMaterial(md));
                }
            }
        } else {
            Material m =  new Material(Shader.Find("Diffuse"));
            m.SetColor("_Color", new Color(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f)); 
            materials.Add("_spc_default", m); 
        }

        GameObject[] ms = new GameObject[buffer.numObjects];
        if(buffer.numObjects == 1) {
            if (!treatasoneobject) { //incase of one geometry but instantiated 
                GameObject go = new GameObject();
                go.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
                go.AddComponent(typeof(MeshFilter));
                go.AddComponent(typeof(MeshRenderer));
                go.name="_spc_rename_";
                ms[0] = go;
            } else {
                gameObject.AddComponent(typeof(MeshFilter));
                gameObject.AddComponent(typeof(MeshRenderer));
                ms[0] = gameObject;
            }
        } else if(buffer.numObjects > 1) {
            for(int i = 0; i < buffer.numObjects; i++) {
                GameObject go = new GameObject();
                go.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
                go.AddComponent(typeof(MeshFilter));
                go.AddComponent(typeof(MeshRenderer));
                ms[i] = go;
            }
        }
        buffer.PopulateMeshes(ms, materials);
        if (!treatasoneobject) {
            foreach(GameObject go in ms) {
                scaleoffset so = objso.Find(delegate(scaleoffset item) { return item.name == go.name; }); 
                if (so!=null) {
                    go.transform.localPosition = ((Vector3.zero-so.MainOffset)*mainso.MasterScale)-((Vector3.zero-mainso.MainOffset)*mainso.MasterScale);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////HELPER FUNCTIONS

    private Texture2D NormalMap(Texture2D source,float strength) {
        strength=Mathf.Clamp(strength,0.0F,10.0F);
        Texture2D result;
        float xLeft;
        float xRight;
        float yUp;
        float yDown;
        float yDelta;
        float xDelta;
        result = new Texture2D (source.width, source.height, TextureFormat.ARGB32, true);
        for (int by=0; by < result.height; by++) {
            for (int bx=0; bx < result.width; bx++) {
                     xLeft = source.GetPixel(bx-1,by).grayscale*strength;
                     xRight = source.GetPixel(bx+1,by).grayscale*strength;
                     yUp = source.GetPixel(bx,by-1).grayscale*strength;
                     yDown = source.GetPixel(bx,by+1).grayscale*strength;
                     xDelta = ((xLeft-xRight)+1)*0.5f;
                     yDelta = ((yUp-yDown)+1)*0.5f;
                result.SetPixel(bx,by,new Color(xDelta,yDelta,1.0f,yDelta));
            }
        }
      result.Apply();
      return result;
    }

    private Texture2D ScaleTexture(Texture2D source,int targetWidth,int targetHeight) {
        Texture2D result=new Texture2D(targetWidth,targetHeight,source.format,true);
        Color[] rpixels=result.GetPixels(0);
        float incX=((float)1/source.width)*((float)source.width/targetWidth);
        float incY=((float)1/source.height)*((float)source.height/targetHeight);
        for(int px=0; px<rpixels.Length; px++) {    
            rpixels[px] = source.GetPixelBilinear(incX*((float)px%targetWidth),incY*((float)Mathf.Floor(px/targetWidth)));
        }
        result.SetPixels(rpixels,0);
        result.Apply();
        return result;
    }

    private string ResolvePath(string filepath,string basepath) {
        string outpath="";
        if (Application.isWebPlayer||basepath.Contains("http://")) { //dealing with webaddress or can't run File.Exists
            //some kind of web url checker
            //Webplayer needs "file://"
            //WWW texloader = new WWW(basepath + txt.Key);
            //yield return texloader;
            //if (texloader.error != null) {    
        } else {
            //File.Exists doesn't like "file://"?
            filepath=filepath.Replace("file://", "");
            filepath=filepath.Replace("file:///", "");
            basepath=basepath.Replace("file://", "");
            basepath=basepath.Replace("file:///", "");
            string sep=Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString();
            string asep;
            if (sep=="\\") {
                asep="/";
            } else {
                asep="\\";
            }
            filepath=filepath.Replace(asep, sep);
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(basepath+filepath)) {
                outpath=basepath+filepath; 
            } else {
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(basepath+Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString()+filepath)) {
                    outpath=basepath+Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString()+filepath;
                } else {
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists(filepath)) {
                        outpath=filepath;
                    } else {
                        string[] fpp=filepath.Split(sep.ToCharArray());
                        string[]    bpp=basepath.Split(sep.ToCharArray());
                        bool found=false;
                        for (int i=(bpp.Length-1);i>=0;i--) {
                            for (int j=(fpp.Length-1);j>=0;j--) {
                                if (!found) {
                                    StringBuilder newpath = new StringBuilder();
                                    for (int k=0;k<i;k++) {
                                        newpath.Append(bpp[k]).Append(sep);
                                    }
                                    for (int k=j;k<fpp.Length;k++) {
                                        newpath.Append(fpp[k]).Append(sep);
                                    }
                                    newpath.Remove(newpath.Length-1, 1);
                                    if (System.IO.File.Exists(newpath.ToString())) {
                                        found=true;
                                        outpath=newpath.ToString();
                                        break;
                                    }                    
                                }
                            }
                            if (found) break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }               
            outpath="file://"+outpath;
        }
        return outpath;
    }

}
```

It works great on PC! 
But when it comes to run application on Android it doesn't load textures.
So i was trying to investigating what cause this issue using ADB and i received this:

```
I/Unity   (22351): NullReferenceException
I/Unity   (22351):   at UnityEngine.Material..ctor (UnityEngine.Shader shader) [
0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
I/Unity   (22351):   at OBJ.GetMaterial (.MaterialData md) [0x00000] in <filenam
e unknown>:0
I/Unity   (22351):   at OBJ.Build () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
I/Unity   (22351):   at OBJ+<Load>c__Iterator1.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filenam
e unknown>:0
I/Unity   (22351):
I/Unity   (22351): (Filename:  Line: -1)
```

So here i need your help Guys :) what can cause the difference in work between Android and PC and where is the issue ?